# Usar DataHora Separados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Tenho um campo DataHora e queria usar separado, ou seja, um único campo no banco de dados chamado DataHora do tipo datetime, e manipular este campo com dois editorfor onde eu salvo a data de um editorfor e a hora de outro editorfor no mesmo campo do banco de dados:

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataHora, "Liberar encomenda as", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataHora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) Horas
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataHora, "Liberar encomenda dia", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataHora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
     </div>
</div>
```

**Classe:**

```
 public DateTime DataHora { get; set; }
```

Comment: Você está usando uma camada de Persistência?
Se sim poderia colocar o classe na sua pergunta, existe uma maneira de que não precisa fazer muita coisa se for isso, dependendo até se for sem ORM também dá! Me diz ai como você salva essas informações, poste também o seu `controller`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer necessariamente usar um campo em banco de dados, vai precisar de um *ViewModel* para consolidar data e hora.

## `SeuModel.cs`

```
public DateTime DataHora { get; set; }
```

## `SeuViewModel.cs`

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public TimeSpan Hora { get; set; }
```

## View

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hora, "Liberar encomenda as", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) Horas
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data, "Liberar encomenda dia", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
     </div>
</div>
```

## Controller

```
model.DataHora = viewModel.Data + viewModel.Hora;
```

Ou ainda, você pode definir seu *Model* já com os campos separados, aí não precisa nem do *ViewModel*, nem da lógica do *Controller* acima.

Comment: Se separar no Model ele não vai ter que ter dois campos no banco

Comment: Neste caso @cigano, sua sugestão seria com o "SeuViewModel.CS" seria uma nova classe? Só não entendi esta parte...

Comment: Isso mesmo. Você cria uma classe que não é ligada ao banco de dados, mas é usada por *View* e *Controller*.